# node API hosted onCloud Function gives non-descript `finished with status: 'crash'` error. Is my configuration correct?

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

I have a working node API that I need to deploy to Cloud Functions

**index.js** that is the entry:

```
"use strict";
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const alertsAPI = require('../src/app.js');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(alertsAPI);
```

**../src/app.js**, where the alertsAPI object comes from:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const cors = require('cors')

alertsAPI = express();
alertsAPI.use(cors({ origin: true }))
alertsAPI.use(bodyParser.json())
alertsAPI.set('json spaces', 2)
alertsAPI.use('/', routes)

module.export = alertsAPI;
```

And **./routes.js** holds the routes itself imports and calls logic:

```
var Controller = require('./controller.js')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const controller = new Controller()

    controller.addListener('get_definition', (return_value) => {
        res.status(200).json(return_value)
    })

    controller.getDefinition()
})

...


module.exports = router;
```

This works locally.

**firebase.json** configuration:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**creds.json"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can deploy without error.

But navigating to the output `https://region-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/api/` yields a `Error: could not handle the request`, and the logs say `Function execution took 199 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"`

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate what you expect this code to do, other than crash. It seems to me that you haven't actually implemented a handler for any requests.

Comment: I have. As I said, the handlers are in routes.js. I've added a code snippet from routes.js, to make it obvious. The entire API works when launched locally, the endpoint from the snippet, and others that read, write from a db. The expected behavior is that the same happens when deployed to Cloud Functions at the designated URL.

Comment: Add logging to the expected code path on order to debug this.  Can you trace what's happening?

Comment: Thanks Doug, this is the first bit of node I've written so I had to read up on some topics. The issue was caused by differences in environments. Locally, I was initializing and auth-ing another GCP service "manually" in addition to firing up the api. When deployed to CF that other services "just works" so the "manual" code was redundant and actually causing an error - initializing 2 instances of the app. Thanks for the tip.